# Keras metric implementation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am trying to build a model with Keras that uses a metric : a special f1 score. I am struggling with its implementation.

So far, I have :

```
def f1_metric(y_true,y_pred):
   y_pred = K.one_hot(indices=K.argmax(y_pred,1), num_classes=4)
   arr = np.zeros((4,4))
   for pred,true in zip(y_pred,y_true):
       c_pred = K.constant(K.argmax(pred))
       c_true = K.constant(K.argmax(true))
       arr[c_true][c_pred] += 1
   fn = 2*arr[0][0]/(np.sum(arr[0]) + np.sum(arr.T[0])) if (np.sum(arr[0]) + np.sum(arr.T[0])) != 0 else 0
   fa = 2*arr[1][1]/(np.sum(arr[1]) + np.sum(arr.T[1])) if (np.sum(arr[1]) + np.sum(arr.T[1])) != 0 else 0
   fo = 2*arr[2][2]/(np.sum(arr[2]) + np.sum(arr.T[2])) if (np.sum(arr[2]) + np.sum(arr.T[2])) != 0 else 0
   fp = 2*arr[3][3]/(np.sum(arr[3]) + np.sum(arr.T[3])) if (np.sum(arr[3]) + np.sum(arr.T[3])) != 0 else 0
   return K.constant((fn + fa + fo + fp)/4)
```

The following error appears when I’m using my `f1_metric` function :
`` OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed ``

I do understand that loops cannot be used. I’ve been reading for a while  but still can’t find an alternative.

How could I implement my for loop correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty specific. y_true and y_pred are tensor type, and you can't iterate through them. You can try to convert them into numpy arrays using to_numpy_array(y_pred), do the operations you need to do, and return, as you're already doing, a tensor value.

So no need for K.constant inside the for loop once you turn y_true and y_pred into arrays, but the function must return a tensor value so leave there K.constant((fn + fa + fo + fp)/4).